# $E\bigl(\frac{2}{1+x}\bigr)$ for Beta(2,$\frac{1}{2}$) random variable

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, estimation

Let x ~ Beta (2,$\frac{1}{2}$). Then calculate $E\left(\frac{2}{1+x}\right)$.

So, ${E}[g(X)] = \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x$ .

$\displaystyle f(x;\alpha,\beta) =\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}\, x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1} $

Then $\displaystyle E\left(\frac{2}{1+x}\right)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{2}{1+x}\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}\, x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}dx$

$\displaystyle E\left(\frac{2}{1+x}\right)=\frac{\Gamma(3/2)}{\Gamma(2)\Gamma(1/2)}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{2}{1+x}\, x^{1}(1-x)^{-1/2}dx$

Now what do I do ? Please help.

Comment: "Now what do I do ?" First, straighten the question (confusion between $x$ the variable and $X$ the random variable, wrong integration limits, missing $dx$). Second, use the change of variable $t=\sqrt{1-x}$.

Comment: You gave jam i guess. How did it go?