# Value of constant k which makes the function $f(x)=\frac{k|x|}{(1+|x|)^4}$ a p.d.f.

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $f(x)=\dfrac{k|x|}{(1+|x|)^4}$, $-\infty<x<\infty$.

Then, what is the value for which f(x) is a probability density function ?

f(x) will be a p.d.f. if $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx=1$

$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{k|x|}{(1+|x|)^4}dx=1$

|x| is an even function,so:$\qquad$ $\displaystyle 2\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{kx}{(1+x)^4}dx=1$

How do I solve this? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** You may write

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x}{(1+x)^4}dx =\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(1+x)-1}{(1+x)^4}dx&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(1+x)^3}dx-\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(1+x)^4}dx\\\\
&=\left.-\frac{1}{2 (1+x)^2}\right|_0^{\infty}+\left.\frac{1}{3 (1+x)^3}\right|_0^{\infty}\\\\
&=\frac12-\frac13\\\\
&=\frac16\\\\
\end{align}
$$ giving $$k=3. $$

Comment: I still get scared when I see an integration problem .. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @square_one You are welcome.

Comment: could you please help me with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091716/e-left-frac21x-right-for-beta2-frac12-random-variable

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$2\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{kx}{(1+x)^4} = 2\left[\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{k(1+x-1)}{(1+x)^4}\right] $$
$$=2\left[\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{k}{(1+x)^3}\right] - 2\left[\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{k}{(1+x)^4}\right]$$

Now substitute (1+x) = u and integrate.

Thanks

Satish